# How can I execute a MapReduce jar programatically from another Java Program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have my MapReduce program (DataProfiler.jar) which performs some data profiling by taking in the table name and column name as command line parameters.

```
hadoop -jar DataProfiler.jar -D tableName=MyTable -D columnFamilyName=CF1
```

Is there a way I could wrap this in another java program.  So that I can execute this jar for all the tables (by connecting to the database and getting a list of all the tables and columns).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, instead of calling the `MapReduce` jar from the simple java program, You can write a logic `MapReduce` driver class in a little generic way.

Let's call this class `JobRunner`. You can define `member variables` which will hold the information about `table` and `columns` you need to process. Then you can setup the `MapReduce` configuration and start the job. Technically you are achieving the same but in a little different way. I think it would be a better approach then calling a jar and starting the `MapReduce` job.